# regex: how to capture angularjs pattern in source file with textmate2?

Tags: regex, angularjs, textmate2

I'd like to capture all source file lines matching the following template (actually any img tag where the url contains an angularjs interpolation):

```
<td><img src="rsc/kws.corn.icon.{{cure}}.png">
```

I tried this without success:

```
src="rsc/[^{]*{{[^"]*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the quote was missing. Here is the right regex, which I also improved:

```
src\s*=\s*"rsc/[^{"]*{{[^"]*"
```

Comment: The `\w*` is extremely fishy. You probably mean `\s*`. And there should be no need to escape `\{` inside character class.